# Showing that the following sequence is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\left (x_n \right )_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that there is $\theta \in[0,1)$ with $|x_{n+1} - x_n| \leq \theta^{n}$

for n $\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that $\left (x_n \right )_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence and converge, so far I have done the following:

WLOG suppose m > n:

$|x_{m} - x_n|$ = $|(x_{m}-x_{m-1}) +(x_{m-1}-x_{m-2})+..... + (x_{n+1}-x_n)|$ $\leq$ $|(x_{m}-x_{m-1})| +|(x_{m-1}-x_{m-2})|+..... + |(x_{n+1}-x_n)|$ $\leq$ $\theta^{m-1} + \theta^{m-2}+ ....+\theta^{n}$ = $\theta^{m-1}[1+\theta^{-1}+....\theta^{n-m+1}]$ = $\theta^{m-1} \frac{1- \theta^{n-m+1}}{1-\theta}$ since it is a geometric series. This is where I get stuck I don't know what to do with this fraction or if I'm going in the right direction any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\theta^{m-1}+\theta^{m-2}+\cdots+\theta^{n} \leq \theta^{n} [1+\theta+\theta^{2}+\cdots]=\frac {\theta^{n}} {1-\theta} \to 0$. 
Your mistake was in pulling out the wrong power of $\theta$. That made things difficult.